# Reply to US Design Patent Office Action(amend to lines)

Tags: oa, lines

I have received an office action. In this action, the examiner pointed that, in figure 7, there are some solid contour lines that are not shown in Figs. 1-6.
Could i delete these lines directly or amend them to broken lines?
Look forward to your reply!!!

Answer (score 1):

A basic requirement of design patent application drawings is that all of the views show the same, consistent, item. If a line is solid in one view it needs to solid in other views of the same thing. Design patents can cover alternate embodiments and a feature that is shown as a solid line in one embodiment might be a broken line in another embodiment. An issue you have in amending a drawing is avoiding adding new matter. There is a fine line between a clarification and adding new matter. Fortunately, design application examiners are almost universally helpful and will often look at a faxed proposed drawing on an informal basis before you settle on something you will actually submit.